# MySQL Syntax Issue - ORDER BY - Joomla PHP

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a syntax issue that I can't seem to figure out.  I'm following the Joomla docs found here:

https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#Selecting_Records_from_a_Single_Table

And I'm getting this error:

```
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order DESC' at line 3 SQL=SELECT `id`,`image`,`order`,`status` FROM `vsem6_session_1` ORDER BY order DESC
```

My Query is:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'image', 'order', 'status')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__session_' . $id));
$query->order('order DESC');

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();   

return $results;
```

It works great if I take out the order clause, but of course the results aren't ordered.  I've search high and low and can't figure it out.  Anyone notice anything?  I am 100% certain there is an "order" column in the table.

I tried this, which shows no error, but it still doesn't order properly.

```
$query->orderby('order DESC');
```

Comment: Try `\`order\` DESC` ... order is a reserved word and you need to use backticks to make it work.

Comment: `order` is a reserved word. In a straightforward query you'd need to wrap it in backticks to use it as an identifier in a query. I don't know how you'd do that with the Joomla classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**order** is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) as its used in `order by`. So to solve mysql's confusion you need to mark your use of order as a field name with back ticks

Comment: many thanks, alternatively I just updated the column to 'ordering' to shy away from the reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->order('order DESC');
```

The problem with this is that that you have not used quoteName().

```
$query->order($db->quoteName('order') . 'DESC');
```

Even though you said you would change the field name, I'm adding this for the situation in which someone could not change the name.